# small expected contraction embedding into trees?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, metric-spaces

I learned FRT theorem for probabilistic metric embedding into trees: For any finite metric d, there exists a distribution over *non contracting, small expected expansion* tree metrics.
The theorem can be used for deriving an approximation algorithm of metric related minimization problems.
(http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jrl/teaching/cse525wi15/lectures/lecture10.pdf)

Currently, I want to solve a maximization problem, instead of minimization problem. If I am correct,  FRT theorem cannot be used for maximization problems.
Thus, my question is: Is there an embedding theorem into a distribution over *non expanding, small expected contraction* tree metrics?

Thanks